# Rails activerecord - how to inherit all child associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord, associations

So in my application I have the models People and Outfits. In my show controller for people, I get the list like this:

```
@people = Person.where("description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:description]}%")
```

And in my view I show the outfits of each person like this:

```
<% @people.each do |person| %>
  <p> Name: <%= person.name %> </p>
  <% @outfits = person.outfits %>
  <% @outfits.each do |outfit|
    <p> Name: <%= outfit.name %> </p>
    <p> Description: <%= outfit.description %> </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But loading the outfits for each person, as I load many people on the page, takes too long. Is there some way I can inherit the outfits of each person so I don't have to wait so long for the page to load? Or is the only way to speed this up to make an index between outfits and people? Thanks for any help

Comment: The answers below will help you to optimize the performance of the calls, but you also must limit what you display by adding some sort of pagination or having the ability to progressively show more.

Answer (score 2):

Use a join to load the associated records:

```
@people = Person.eager_load(:outfits)
                .where("description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:description]}%")
                .limit(20) # optional
```

Otherwise you have what is called a N+1 query issue where each iteration through `@people` will cause a separate database query to fetch outfits.

And yes the `outfits.person_id` or whatever column that creates the association should have a foreign key index. Using the `belongs_to` or `references` macro in the migration will do this by default:

```
create_table :outfits do |t|
  t.belongs_to :person, foreign_key: true
end
```

- [Active Record Query Interface - Eager Loading Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)
- [Making sense of ActiveRecord joins, includes, preload, and eager_load](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2017/01/24/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where)

Comment: plus an offset to help with the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

you should set a limit like this:

```
@people = Person.where("description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:description]}%").limit(20)
```

change the number according to your preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.joins` or `.includes`

If you have a table full of Person and you use a :joins => outfits to pull in all the outfit information for sorting purposes, etc it will work fine and take less time than :include, but say you want to display the Person along with the outfit name, description, etc. To get the information using :joins, it will have to make separate SQL queries for each user it fetches, whereas if you used :include this information is ready for use.

Solution

```
Person.includes(:outfits).where("description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:description]}%")
```

Comment: If you know that you are using the data in the joined table it is better to use `.eager_load` as includes will use two separate queries.